# What font is used in this image?

Tags: font

Can someone tell what font was used to write "november"? I really like the look of it but cannot tell the font ...

[image]

Comment: Probably best asked on doctype.com where there are more graphic designers.

Comment: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/ is also a very good place for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Futura.

Here's a screenshot of the same text in Futura on my computer:

[image]

Some of the clues that indicate it's the same font:

- The perfectly round **o**
- The point at the bottom of the **v**
- The flat angles at the top and bottom of the **b**'s vertical bar (and other similar vertical bars, like on the **n** and the **r**)
- The perfectly geometric **e**, and the angle of the **e**'s point
- The shape of the round part of the **b** -- it's based on two circles that are slightly offset, so it's narrower toward the left and thicker toward the bottom right

Answer (score 6):

Using identifont.com this looks like Futura. Possibly Futura, Futura (BT) or Futura (URW).

Here's a direct link to the font search I performed: http://www.identifont.com/identify?16+november+1IU+N2Q+97+23+9M+31+F2U+F+9D+7UX+NQE+PAF+G39+9J+9Z+L+M

The Identify Result section on the left shows the other two Futura options lower on the list.

Comment: Thanks for sharing http://www.identifont.com, I didn't know this one!